tailwind/css div won't expand
I'm trying to get the light blue div to take up the whole screen space, but it won't. Additionally, the dark blue div shows even when no content is in it, but not the light blue one despite setting max-height (tried with min-height too)
<body>
    <div class="bg-blue-500 min-w-full min-h-10"></div>
    <div class="bg-blue-400 max-h-full w-1/4">a</div>
<body>

Setting min-h-10 and below works for the light blue (bg-blue-400) but not any value above that.
what it looks like

For me, the dark blue doesn't show. And you do you wish the light blue to stretch down and to the right?

min-height works even when there is no height, and the max-height works only when there is height.

min-height works even when there is no height, and the max-height works only when there is height.
A minimum guarantees a minimum and a max can be greater than the default value.
codesandbox sample
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/peaceful-christian-35ynj8?file=%2Findex.html%3A12%2C43

Try
<body>
    <div class="bg-blue-500 min-w-full h-10"></div>
    <div class="bg-blue-400 h-screen w-screen w-1/4">a</div>
</body>

